# How to exclude directory and files inside it - rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have Nginx rule that is working good:

```
rewrite ^/myapp/(.*)/$ /myapp/good-file.php?param=$1;
```

But if I visit some directory under /myapp/, it loads above .php instad real sub-directory that has got its own index.php, example if I visit:

```
http://www.example.com/myapp/sub-directory/
```

It loads things from good-file.php because rewrite rule is working (it must be).

How can I exclude /myapp/sub-directory/ and files inside it if I have that kink of rewrite?

Thanks a lot for provided information and help!

Comment: Do you know Rewrite Condition and Rewrite Rule? You need to tell server that if not found as directory then apply the rule!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `try_files` directive to test for the presence of files and directories prior to taking a default action (such as your rewrite rule). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

A possible implementation is:

```
location /myapp {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/myapp/(.*)/$ /myapp/good-file.php?param=$1 last;
}
```

*The above assumes you have a `root` and `index` defined, and a location to handle files ending with `.php`.*